# A bug about cin, is there a problem with the configuration file?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   string a;
   cin >> a;
   cout << a;
}
```

Here's my code, so simple.
When I use code-runner plugin, the cin function can read the Chinese characters in the input stream correctly, but when compiling with the `task.json` file, there is a bug, the same Chinese characters are outputted in several runs with different characters, why?
Here's my `task.json`.

```
     {
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe 生成活动文件",
            "command": "D:\\msys2\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "调试器生成的任务。"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: ***is there a problem with the configuration file?*** No. I don't think your tasks.json is broken assuming you have a single cpp file.

Comment: Did you try to compile it using g++ in a terminal? If the error persists then as @dreschejm said there is nothing wrong with your tasks.js

Comment: When I manually compile with the commands g++ -g hello.cpp -o hellp, the program is working fine @apetrai

Comment: @helloCPP When you configured the project did you select g++ as the compiler in vs code?

Comment: Yes, I did the compilation in g++. I found an interesting problem, whether it is automatic compilation using configuration files or manual compilation using directives, the cin function in vscode's integrated terminal gives a very strange error, but opening the exe file directly in windows OS, this error does not occur. Also, the error does not occur in the vscode integrated terminal when compiling automatically with the run-code plugin. This is a very strange phenomenon.@apetrai